# exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Before reading: I know the table is too weird and long and it needs to be normalized; but for some reason this is my database and I should work with this table! Sorry about that!
To keep it short:
I'm getting the following exception:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid
>   parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of
>   tokens' in C:\xampp\htdocs\FD\includes\helper.php:472 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\FD\includes\helper.php(472): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\FD\newHrForm.php(113):
>   helperFunctions::UpdateTableHrForms('112', 'dfsfdsfds',
>   '3123213', 'dfdsf', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
>   '3213123213', '1', '3213123', '213123213', '3213213', '213123123',
>   ) #2 {main}

and my function to save data is as following:

```
public static function UpdateTableHrForms(
        $id,$dob_city,$dob_province,$dob_country,...) 
            {

                $conn = new mysqlcon();
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                $query = "INSERT into `hr_forms` (`id`,`dob_city`,
                    `dob_province`,`dob_country`,...)
                    VALUES (:id,:dob_city,:dob_province,:dob_country,...)";




                try {
                    if (helperFunctions::CheckidExistForms($id) == 0) {
                        $result = $conn->prepare($query);                               
                        $result->execute(array('id'=>$id,'dob_city'=>$dob_city,'dob_province'=>$dob_province,'dob_country'=>$dob_country));



                        $Msg = "<div style=\"text-align:center;\" class=\"alert alert-success\">
                                    <strong>Tips! </strong>
                                        Data is successfully saved to database.
                                    <button class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" type=\"button\">&times;</button>
                                </div>";
                    } else {
                        $Msg = "<div style=\"text-align:center;\" class=\"alert alert-error\">
                                    <strong>Error! </strong>
                                        This employee information is already existed in the system.
                                    <button class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" type=\"button\">&times;</button>
                                </div>";
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $e->getMessage();
                    $Msg = $e; /* "<div style=\"text-align:center;\" class=\"alert alert-error\">
                      <strong>Error! </strong>
                      This employee information cannot save in the system.
                      <button class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" type=\"button\">&times;</button>
                      </div>"; */
                }
                return $Msg;
}
```

When I replace the values of my insert method (in UpdateTableHrForms with the one that error gives me and run it in mysql; there is no error; but in PHP it is giving me the error; Could you please help me if I'm doing something wrong?)

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn about database normalization.  No SQL statement should be that big.  No SQL table should have that many columns.

Comment: PS: I know the table is too weird and long and it needs to be normalized; but for some reason this is my database and I should work with this table!

Comment: It is telling you that the number of columns declared does not match the number of values giving into the INSERT statement. So ultimately you are doing either `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) values ('val1','val2')` or you are doing `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) values ('val1','val2','val3')`. You need to go through your code and make sure you are passing the correct number of columns and values

Answer (score 2):

The array you're passing to `execute` isn't formatted quite right; you need to have the colon at the start of the parameter name.

It should be:

```
array(':id'=>$id,':dob_city'=>....
```

Comment: Thanks for helping; I added right now; but still the exception does not disapear!

Comment: Ok; I changed it now; there were simply lots of fields and the number of fields did not match; I used MS Excel to make sure and solved the problem :-) Thanks everyone

Comment: @ShimaMdz - you can add that as a new answer and accept it when you're able.